# Timimg of 4060 counter-oscillator

Tags: counter

I'm using a CD4060B counter/oscillator and need to know the internal timing of the RESET operation. TI's [4060B datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4060b.pdf) says that the minimum input reset pulse width is 30 ns at 10 V, and the reset propagation delay is 80 ns.

When calculating the time for a RESET does the propagation time start *after* the minimum Reset pulse width?  Then is the output transition time of 50 ns added for a complete reset operation?

Answer (score 0):

The \$t_{PHL}\$Reset = off prop delay is more than double the \$t_W\$ Reset=on (H) minimum pulse width .

The \$t_{PHL}\$Off delay begins after the leading edge of Reset= ON \$t_W\$ width so it these delays are not cumulative.